# Notion API: Reminders

Tags: notion-api

Is there an API which exposes the reminders added to pages? I would like to sync Notion reminders to my central reminder application, therefore, I'm not managing reminders in multiple places and can have one view of all my reminders.

Answer (score 0):

No, Notion's API does not expose reminders currently.

However, you could instead make a Notion database of reminders, and have links to pages or [linked databases](https://www.notion.so/Linked-databases-fb007e2798d04c57aee839ecf6ce450a) to access them from other pages.